# jQuery define two elements in one variable

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to define two elements in one variable.

For example:

```
var replacer = $(".ir a") && $(".tk a");
```

Comment: We could possibly offer better solutions, were we able to see your relevant (minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML.

Comment: Basically I have an .each function() and I wanted to have it run inside the two divs, which it works now.  I didn't want to have to write two .each functions() cause that would slow the performance down.

Comment: The additional information is always appreciated, but it's not as useful as seeing the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var replacer = $('.ir a, .tk a');
```

Or:

```
var replacer = $('a').filter(function(){
                   return $(this).closest('.ir').length ||  $(this).closest('.tk').length
               });
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'd be glad to have been either of those things, to be *both* is especially welcome! =)